# Xcode не компилирует проект: clang failed with exit code 255

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> `clang: error: unable to execute command: posix_spawn failed: Argument list too long
> clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
> Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
> Target: i386-apple-darwin11.4.2
> Thread model: posix`

Comment: `:((((((`[]()

Comment: первый же вопрос, и четыре дислайка

Comment: Вообще и не, говорите, пришлось поотвечать в других вопросах, чтобы репутацией поделиться с Артемом.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

с 99% вероятностью проблема в #import, где то ушло в рекурсию.

Comment: Дак уже гит откатил на 3 ревизии. что интересно, вчера уходил все работало, сегодня весь день борюсь :((((

Comment: Локальные настройки проекта тоже в git хранятся? Значит, надо посмотреть на конфиги и файлы, которые вне git и которые изменялись.

Comment: Ну вся папка загитована проекта. с потрохами. Ок спасибо за идею, сейчас гляну.

Comment: Урааа спасибо большое за наводку!! В зависимостях изменения нашел. Они отдельно от проекта лежат, все поправил все заработало!!! Спасибо Артем.